# Custom Mailchimp sign up form not working

Tags: jquery, forms, mailchimp, fieldset

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery validate to make my sign up section on my site look nice. I then want this to link to a Mailchimp list. 
I have built the working front end and have looked at the Mailchimp [page](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/advanced-customization-of-mailchimps-sign-up-forms) here on how to link the two up, unfortunately I just can't get it to work.

It's a fair amount of code so, including the additional validate.js 
The site is up [here](http://www.shiftswap.me)

This is the code that Mail chimp suggest I need to edit.

```
<form action="http://shiftswap.us5.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="u" value="09ea39478ba4b316411db0a2f">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="aff40c7e1a">
<div id="mergeTable" class="mergeTable">
<div class="mergeRow dojoDndItem mergeRow-text" id="mergeRow-1">
<label for="MERGE1">First Name</label>
<div class="field-group">
<input type="text" name="MERGE1" id="MERGE1" size="25" value="">
</div>
</div>
```

And the code from the site (- the js and other elements)
    
    
    
    Your name
    
    
    
    
    
    Your email
    
    
    
    
    
    Submit

I would very much appreciate any help anyone is able to offer.

Thank-you in advance.